# C++ Any pointer as function argument

Tags: c++, function, pointers, arguments

Here are some sample classes to reproduce the situation I'm facing:

```
class A {
B* seccond;
}
class B {
int * number;
}
static NTSTATUS Read(std::uintptr_t address, size_t size, PVOID buff);

// Let's assume we have object 'obj' which has valid address of number variable

int buff;
Read(obj.seccond, sizeof(int), &buff);

Error:  cannot convert argument 1 from 'int *' to 'uintptr_t'
```

I know it can be fixed easily with:

```
Read(std::uintptr_t(obj.seccond), sizeof(int), &buff);
```

but this is not satisfying enough, since it lowers code readability and it's just ugly. I really don't want to use templates since they're already everywhere all over my code.
Is there any simple container for such variables? Or some more elegant way of doing it?

EDIT: I've re-adapted question, sorry

Comment: `std::uintptr_t` is not a pointer type, it's an integer. Implicit conversion would cause plenty of problems (look at the history of C for examples).

Comment: *templates are already everywhere all over your code* ... Make one more :)

Comment: I know but the case is I'm working on other process address space which structures holds pointers, once I read them they should be treated as normal uint values which are to be passed to `Read` function. So there is no way of doing that?

Comment: By the way, that code doesn't cause that error - `obj.seccond` is a `B*`, not an `int*`. And storing "foreign" addresses as normal pointers is very fragile.

Comment: The reasoning behind this, is that I wanted to use exact same structures as my target is using. Yes, code isn't causing this error, because of changes I've made in my edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use overload to do the conversion at one place

```
static NTSTATUS Read(const void* p, size_t size, PVOID buff)
{
    return Read(std::uintptr_t(p), size, buff);
}
```

Comment: I was so sure I have tried it, sorry for problem guys and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using one `int*` since your function wait for `uintptr_t`.
One is signed, the other is unsigned.

Try to use `unsigned` instead of `int` or try to use `std::intptr_t` instead of `std::uintptr_t`

EDIT :
A way to solve your problem could be something like that :

```
class B {
    int *number;
    operator int*() {
        return number;
    }
};
```

After, you can do something like :
`Read(*objA.second, ...);`

The answer from Jarod42 can be good as well !

Comment: I probably wrongly asked my question, could you take a look now?
The problem is not signed-unsigned, but the must conversion to std::uintptr_t which holds address of object in memory.

Comment: look at my edit, and look to the answer from @Jarod42 :).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use a void pointer as an argument.For example:

```
static NTSTATUS Read(void* address, size_t size, PVOID buff);
```

But you should probably pass an other argument to the function in order to determine the type that you should cast the address variable to.So for example:

```
static NTSTATUS Read(void* address,unsigned code, size_t size, PVOID buff)
{
     //code could be int=1,float=2,...
     switch(code)
     {
         //handle each case int,float,custom type ...
         //by casting the address to the corresponding type(code)
     }
}
```